# Avoid confusion of IDs when two users create post at the same time?

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a site where a user can create a post and upload a couple of images for that post. When the user creates a post, I need to get the ID of the post that is about to be created in order to create a folder (with a corresponding name) for the uploaded images. The table "posts" has autoincrementation on "id". I have tried using the logic pasted in below, but I have a feeling that it's not the way to go.

```
editData("LOCK TABLES posts READ");
$highest = getRow("SELECT MAX(id)+1 AS id FROM posts");
$_SESSION["id"] = $highest["id"];
editData("UNLOCK TABLES");
```

I then use the value of `$_SESSION["id"]` for the creation of the folder for the images, but it doesn't seem completely foolproof.

What I want to achieve is basically to manage the situation where two users starts creating a post at the same time. In this case, I need to be sure that the images that user A has uploaded does not get confused with the ones being uploaded by user B. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Note that `>` is Markdown for quotes. For code, all you need are those extra four spaces at the start of the line.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not do it this way. A better option (among several) could be

- make the new post. is neccesairy make it invisible until everything is finished
- get the last inserted id. MySQL has a function for this, and it will retrieve the last ID from your session, so other users don't mess with your number
- add the images.

If you are worried about thread-safety of this, read the following quote from the MySQL manual"

> "The last ID that was generated is
>   maintained in the server on a
>   per-connection basis. This means the
>   value the function returns to a given
>   client is the most recent
>   AUTO_INCREMENT value generated by that
>   client. The value cannot be affected
>   by other clients, even if they
>   generate AUTO_INCREMENT values of
>   their own. This behavior ensures that
>   you can retrieve your own ID without
>   concern for the activity of other
>   clients, and without the need for
>   locks or transactions."

We are talking about **connection** based "last", so that means you are not influenced by other inserts. Also, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Comment: I see what you mean, but the last inserted id might as well (at least in theory) be the id of the post user B has just created rather than the one of user A, if you see what I mean.

Comment: Yep, but you don't have to worry about that, since you are requestion the last inserted id of this connection

Answer (score 0):

I would create a temporary directory to upload the files to. You can use PHP [rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) as part of the directory name to ensure uniqueness, then get a new ID then rename the directory as part of the upload process.

Answer (score 0):

In the file that handle's the form you should insert the pictures, then get the id of them and create the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would approach it:

```
//create the table (with a boolean value to keep it hidden until everything is done)
$r = mysql_query("INSERT INTO foo VALUES(x, y, z, false)");
//retrieve the auto_increment id
$post = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT id FROM foo WHERE x=x y=y z=z..."), MYSQL_ASSOC);
//create your dir with the id and your image uploads
do_stuff();
//flip the boolean field
mysql_query("UPDATE foo SET show=true WHERE id=$id");
```

Comment: This might be the way to go, though in my case, a bit complicated, since the fileupload takes place via ajax before the actual post is created (that is: before the form is submitted). So I would have to call some kind of save method before doing the actual upload. But thanks, I think this is the way to go :-)

Comment: if you MUST upload first, then just create a temp directory named from the hash of one of the post details or username of whoever is creating it, $dir_name = sha(post_title); then move all the stuff afterwards

Answer (score 0):

Just return the mysql_insert_id...